# USB devices not recognized if not plugged at boot Kubuntu 19.10

Tags: boot, usb, kubuntu

I had installed Kubuntu 18.04 and then upgraded to 19.10 on my laptop and on a desktop computer and the two present the same problem.
USB devices are not recognized if not plugged in at boot (at the GRUB screen).
I tried on 18.04 and even after the upgrade to 19.10 the problem still persists. On Windows (dual-boot) the usb periphericals works.
After booting and landed on desktop screen I tried to plug-in a fat32 formatted USB pen and launched the `sudo fdisk -l` command but all I can see are the SSD drive partitions.
Packages installed that may cause conflict:
-**samhain**- (?)
I even tried to install -**usbmount**- package but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was the package `lockdown` to cause conflict.

I removed it and now the usb devices get mounted as normal, even wifi in my laptop now works!

Now I upgraded my system to Kubuntu 20.04 and the `lockdown` feature is implemented at kernel level (Linux 5.4), so there's no need to install the package from apt.